# Need help identify the purpose of some Perls commands

Tags: perl

I have this Perl script that I need to understand to correct a bug in a program I'm using.

```
my %offsets;
my $def = ">gm_dna.fa_1   Sck3bRy_190_HRSCAF_380 CHUNK number:0 size:9149333 offset:0     1       8479";
my $file = "test1.fasta"


if($def =~ /^.*\; (\d+)$/){
     $offsets{Cwd::abs_path($file)} = $1;
}
```

I never used Perl before and I'm at lost

What this script is supposed to do (especially the if block), what `($def =~ /^.*\; (\d+)$/)` and `$offsets{Cwd::abs_path($file)} = $1;` are supposed to do?

Comment: The snippet  $def =~ /^.*\; (\d+)$/  does a regula expression match on the hardcoded string $def. Beware that there is no match, as the pattern expects a semicolon and $def does not contain a semicolon the match will fail. Therefore  $offsets{Cwd::abs_path($file)} = $1;  will never be executed. In case of a match $1 would contain the numer at the end of $def. Cwd::abs_paths($file) gives you the absolute path of test1.fasta. The absolute path is used as a key for the hashmap %offsets. For dealing with genomic sequences I recommend that you take a look at BioPerl.

Comment: In that case, how in Perl could I make it match with the current $def, which is separated by a tabulation
could i simply change the ; by a \t like this :
`($def =~ /^.*\\t (\d+)$/)`

Answer (score 0):

the code

`($def =~ /^.*\; (\d+)$/)`

says that if the `$def` variable matches a certain regex ending with at least one  number (indicated by `(\d+)`, which could be `1` or `8479`, etc.) to save it to `$1`, and assign that decimal number to the hash `%offsets` which will save the absolute path of this file.

This particular string `$def` does not match the regex, as it doesn't have a `;` within.

Comment: In that case, is it possible that both are kept sad saved in $1 ?

Comment: $1 only contains the string.  Here, however, your code will never enter the `if` statement because the regex doesn't match, as the `;` is missing.